# understanding co library and javascript generator with example

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, co

I am trying to understanding co libary  -
https://github.com/tj/co
and using this library with promises. I am using following code as example -

```
const co = require('co');

function foo(x) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        console.log('I am starting foo');
        const y = 8;
        console.log('I have passed y');
        const z = 16;
        resolve(x + y + z);
    });
}   

co(function* () {
    console.log('I Start');
    yield foo(5);
    console.log('I finish');
});
```

On running this code, 'I finish' never log to console.

I could not understand why it is not printing 'I finish' into console.

Thanks

Comment: Does it log `I am starting foo`?

Comment: It should work just fine, what does it print to the console?

Comment: it Log - 'i Start', 'I am Starting foo' and 'I have passed y',

Comment: works for me exactly as it is.  (node v6.9.0, co 4.6.0).  What version of node are you using?

Comment: sorry on running node app.js it does print all the console, i was using vscode command, sorry again and thanks